# Why not say "we do chicken rightly"?

Tags: adverbs

This is a commonly heard slogan:

> We do chicken right.

I understand which means "we cook chicken in a right way" ,and the word **right** to be adverbial.

1,But why not use the adverb form **rightly** instead?
2, Does it mean adjective phrases can serve as adverbial? 
Similarly:

> the plane landed **safe**.

Comment: Advertising slogans aren't always strictly grammatical; they choose something that sounds punchy and memorable. To me, it recalls the phrase 'do right _by_ someone', meaning to treat them in a proper manner.

Comment: Because English is seldom logical, and *rightly* isn't an idiomatic adjective. For an idiomatic adjective in that sentence, use *correctly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adverbal form of right isn't usually "rightly", but "right".

Most adjectives can be changed to adverbs by adding "-ly" for example "angry->angrily". Other adjectives must be used without changing them, such as "fast->fast". Some can be used in both ways, perhaps with a slight difference in meaning. So we can say

He spoke angrily
He ran fast
He drives quick
He drives quickly

The particular choice of adverb depends on idiom.  In the case of "right" you can say

> He rightly says "the sun is a star".

But in most other cases the adverb is "right"

> We cook chicken right.
>   Do it right or don't do it at all!
>   It is right beside you.
>   The train arrived right on time.

In etymology, these adverbs are derived from Old English *rihte* but the adjective and "rightly" are derived from Old English *riht*.  The distinction between the adverb and adjective has been lost in modern English.